# How to get one KinematicBody2D to push another?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, physics, movement, godot

I am working in Godot 3, where my player is a `KinematicBody2D`. When I collide with a block which is also a `KinematicBody2D` I'd like my player to push it without losing velocity.

My block is in a group called `moveables`, has no script, and has no other forces acting on it.

After I calculate the velocity of my player in `_physics_process()`, I have the following code.

```
# update position and handle collision

var collision = move_and_collide(vel * delta)
if collision:
    var collider = collision.collider
    var normal = collision.normal
    var remainder = collision.remainder
    var collision_angle = rad2deg(acos(normal.dot(Vector2(0,-1))))

    # floors
    if collision_angle == 0:

        # reset y vel so it doesn't keep accumulating
        vel.y = 0

        var horizontal_movement = Vector2(remainder.x, 0)
        move_and_collide(horizontal_movement)

    # moveables
    elif collision_angle == 90:
        if collider in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("moveables"): 
                collider.move_and_collide(remainder) # move block by remainder
                move_and_collide(remainder) # move player by remainder
```

This code does allow the player to push the block, but only slowly. I can't figure out why. Ideally, the player would push the block without losing any velocity.

Even if I directly update only the horizontal position of my block, it still moves slower than expected, and my player sprite is blurred, presumably because of collision corrections.

```
        if collider in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("moveables"): 
            collider.global_position.x += remainder.x
            move_and_collide(remainder)
```

The problem seems to be that when I move the player by the remainder, the player is still colliding with the block, even though I move the block itself in the previous line. This is confirmed by analyzing the collision object `move_and_collide(remainder)`.

**What's wrong and how can I achieve the desired movement?**

I asked a variant of this question on a Godot forum, but am also asking it here for increased visibility.

Comment: Why did you decide to make the block a KinematicBody2D? From the [Godot documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_kinematicbody2d.html): "Kinematic bodies are special types of bodies that are meant to be user-controlled. They are not affected by physics at all (to other types of bodies, such a character or a rigid body, these are the same as a static body)" - this seems ill-suited to an object you want to push around with physics. Is using a [RigidBody2D](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_rigidbody2d.html#class-rigidbody2d) for the block a viable option?

Comment: RigidBody2D uses Godot's in-built physics (it requires you to specify friction, mass, gravity scale). KinematicBody2D allows you to specify all movement yourself, and gives you more control. Because my player is a KinematicBody2D, the block should also be, I think. Especially because a KinematicBody2D cannot interact with a RigidBody2D, except by manually detecting collision between them, and then calling `add_force()` or `apply_impulse()` on the RigidBody2D (similar to what I'm doing already). There should be a simple way to do this with two KinematicBody2Ds, but I've yet to figure it out.

Comment: KinematicBody2D is a good choice for when your physics are simple and you want to implement them yourself in code, like eg. the pieces on a chess board or the blocks of a Sokoban. If you want to rely on Godot to handle the physics, however, it's much easier to use a RigidBody2D and handle any adjustments to the default physics in the physics process callback.
If you want to use a KinematicBody2D, you have to add collision areas to your blocks, check for the presence of the player character's body and inherit its horizontal movement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will add `RayCast2Ds` to each side of the block and alter the block's position depending on the player's velocity (as long as certain other conditions are met).